# 7 - Attachments are not showing in search results for non admins when using apache solr attachments

Tags: 7, users, search

I am using apache solr search module in my site, and using local Tika extraction for indexing attachments.

When I logged in as admin I can able to search attachments as well as nodes, but if I logged in as other user attachments are not showing up in search results, only nodes are showing.

Do I need to do any settings for this? I have provided Seach permissions for all the users in people tab.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One dirty hack for this problem is: **Disable Apache Solr Access module** and than the file search should work fine for other users as well.

But first check if there are permission available for Solr Access, if not than you may try this hack and see if this works.

Comment: Hi Ankit, your hack worked well. There are no permissions available for solr access module. Any way thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vamshi Glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the Apache Solr Access *and* the attachments, see the issue here which has a patch: https://drupal.org/node/1782936